# INSERT INTO with SubQuery MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

I have this Statement:

```
INSERT INTO qa_costpriceslog (item_code, invoice_code, item_costprice)
    VALUES (1, 2, (SELECT item_costprice FROM qa_items WHERE item_code = 1));
```

I'm trying to insert a value copy the same data of item_costprice, but show me the error:

```
Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

How i can solve this?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Use numeric literals with aliases inside a `SELECT` statement.  No `()` are necessary around the `SELECT` component.

```
INSERT INTO qa_costpriceslog (item_code, invoice_code, item_costprice)
  SELECT
    /* Literal number values with column aliases */
    1 AS item_code,
    2 AS invoice_code,
    item_costprice
  FROM qa_items 
  WHERE item_code = 1;
```

Note that in context of an `INSERT INTO...SELECT`, the aliases are not actually necessary and you can just `SELECT 1, 2, item_costprice`, but in a normal `SELECT` you'll need the aliases to access the columns returned.

Answer (score 12):

You can just simply e.g.

```
INSERT INTO modulesToSections (fk_moduleId, fk_sectionId, `order`) VALUES
    ((SELECT id FROM modules WHERE title="Top bar"),0,-100);
```

Comment: `Error in query (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row ` -> syntax is correct, but that's only for single row.

Comment: Always better to put a limit state when using sub query like the answer. Eg: Select id from modules where title="Top bar" limit 1

Comment: this works, but is there a better way to do it that doesnt involve putting a subquery in each row that i want to add?

Answer (score 4):

I was disappointed at the "all or nothing" answers. I needed (again) to `INSERT` some data and `SELECT` an `id` from an existing table.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id_table2, name) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM table2 LIMIT 1), 'Example');
```

The sub-select on an `INSERT` query should use parenthesis in addition to the comma as deliminators.

For those having trouble with using a `SELECT` within an `INSERT` I recommend testing your `SELECT` independently first and ensuring that the correct number of columns match for both queries.

Answer (score 2):

Your insert statement contains too many columns on the left-hand side or not enough columns on the right hand side.  The part before the VALUES has 7 columns listed, but the second part after VALUES only has 3 columns returned: 1, 2, then the sub-query only returns 1 column.

**EDIT:** Well, it did before someone modified the query....

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote to the good answer of Michael Berkowski:
You can also dynamically add fields (or have them prepared if you're working with php skripts) like so:

```
   INSERT INTO table_a(col1, col2, col3)
     SELECT
       col1,
       col2,
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
     FROM table_B 
     WHERE b.col1 = a.col1;
```

If you need to transfer *without adding new data*, you can use NULL as a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple string values you want to add, you can put them into a temporary table and then cross join it with the value you want.

```
-- Create temp table    
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE NewStrings (
        NewString VARCHAR(50)
    );
-- Populate temp table
INSERT INTO NewStrings (NewString) VALUES ('Hello'), ('World'), ('Hi');

-- Insert desired rows into permanent table
INSERT INTO PermanentTable (OtherID, NewString)
    WITH OtherSelect AS (
        SELECT OtherID AS OtherID FROM OtherTable WHERE OtherName = 'Other Name'
    )
    SELECT os.OtherID, ns.NewString
    FROM OtherSelect os, NewStrings ns;
```

This way, you only have to define the strings in one place, and you only have to do the query in one place. If you used subqueries like I initially did and like Elendurwen and John suggest, you have to type the subquery into every row. But using temporary tables and a CTE in this way, you can write the query only once.