# Issue with a subquery to insert a value in a table from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I want to insert a value to a table where parent value for all values being inserted is some entry from the same table "`master`".

I used the subquesry with aliases as suggested on [INSERT INTO with SubQuery MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644149/insert-into-with-subquery-mysql)

```
INSERT INTO mdl_question_categories (NAME, stamp, parent, info) 
SELECT 
  'cat100' AS NAME,
  'localhost+140117065545+AUXF' AS stamp,
  id 
FROM
  mdl_question_categories 
WHERE NAME = 'master',
  'desc' AS info ;
```

This code throws an error

`Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''desc' as info' at line 1
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1064`

Then I changed the query to

```
INSERT INTO mdl_question_categories (NAME, stamp, info, parent) 
SELECT 
  'cat100' AS NAME,
  'localhost+140117065545+AUXF' AS stamp,
  'desc' AS info,
  id 
FROM
  mdl_question_categories 
WHERE NAME = 'master' ;
```

This works excellent.

Now the question is why did this happen?

Is there any restriction that we should always keep the value picking sql part `id from mdl_question_categories where name='master'` at the end of query part?

Comment: Now the question is - what do you want from `AS` (aliasing) in `WHERE` clause ?

Comment: @Strawberry irrelevant, that is string literal in case of query above (it's enclosed by quotes)

Comment: Ahaaaa!!!! 
@AlmaDo  you pointed something very important that I was ignoring +1 to you.

Comment: `SELECT 
  'cat100' AS NAME,
  'localhost+140117065545+AUXF' AS stamp,
  (id 
FROM
  mdl_question_categories 
WHERE NAME = 'master') as parent,
  'desc' AS info ;`

Answer (score 4):

You are INSERTing 4 values: `name,stamp,info, parent`

In your old query, you were SELECTing 3 values `'cat100' as name,'localhost+140117065545+AUXF' as stamp, id`. Whereas `'desc' AS info` at the end was considered to be the part of `WHERE` clause (and not part of the `SELECT`) thus producing an error.

However in your new query you are correctly SELECTing 4 values (which matches the INSERT): `'cat100' AS NAME, 'localhost+140117065545+AUXF' AS stamp, 'desc' AS info, id`

Comment: Nope, In first query also the op selects 4 . `SELECT 
  'cat100' AS NAME,
  'localhost+140117065545+AUXF' AS stamp,
  id 
FROM
  mdl_question_categories 
WHERE NAME = 'master',
  'desc' AS info ;`. The actual mistake was the OP missed column aliasing or he/she should surround with ()

Answer (score 1):

Here I modified the query

```
insert into mdl_question_categories (name,stamp,parent,info)
select 'cat100' as name,
'localhost+140117065545+AUXF' as stamp,
id from mdl_question_categories
where name in('master','desc')
```

B'coz if you are giving the where condition like that it won't work.

Comment: no I didn't mean `where name in ('master','desc')`;
`info` value is `'desc'` in the insert query

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all the values on the `select` line.  You seem to have moved one value *after* the query.  Try this:

```
INSERT INTO mdl_question_categories (NAME, stamp, parent, info) 
    SELECT 'cat100' AS NAME, 'localhost+140117065545+AUXF' AS stamp, id , 'desc' AS info
    FROM
      mdl_question_categories 
    WHERE NAME = 'master'
```