# Quotation marks in SQL attribute-name enumeration

Tags: mysql, sql

While searching for an answer to another problem, I found an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32634993) containing a Insert-SQL-statement with a word in single quotation marks in the attribute-enumeration. I have never seen this before. Dose it have any purpose or is it just a mistake by the author of the comment?

See " 'order' ":

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name_first, name_last, `order`)
VALUES (....);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word in MySQL and a keyword in SQL.  That makes it a really bad choice for a column name.

But someone chose it anyway.  Sigh.

The backticks escape the column name so it is not confused with the `order` in `order by`.

As a note:  There is a mistake, but the mistake is in allowing a name such as `order` for a column.  I mean, even `ordering` is fine.

Comment: "but the mistake is in allowing a name such as order for a column" is simply not true.... But it is advise not to use a reserved word.